# Implement opentracing in Spring Boot for Datadog

Tags: spring-boot, trace, datadog, opentracing

I need to implement tracing opentracing (opentelementary) for datadog in my Spring Boot application with rest controller.

I have a given kubernetes endpoint, to which I should send traces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully grasp the issue. Here are some steps to collect your traces:

1. Enable trace collection on Kubernetes and open relevant port (8126) [doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/daemonset_setup/?tab=k8sfile#apm-and-distributed-tracing)
2. Configure your app to send traces to the right container. Here is an example to adapt based on your situation. [doc on java
   instrumentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup/java/)

```
        env:
          - name: DD_AGENT_HOST
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Just in case, more info on Open Tracing [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/advanced/opentracing/?tab=java)